# Ordering DataTable, but take care of Case Sensitivity and signs

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

How do I sort alphabetically a `DataTable`, but in the same time sorting rule must take care of case, upper in front of lower, and sign does not take first place in front of latters!

Example: 
I want record "**AX**ialis" in front of "**Al**l people", "**FP**rint" to be in front of "**Fi**nger Print", "MyRecordV2" in front of "MyRecord**_**v2" even if in a normal order it will be "All people", "AXialis", "Finger Print", "FPrint", "MyRecord_v2", "MyRecordV2"

Comment: Roll your own compare-method. Check https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c for instructions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design DataViews can only be sorted using `StringComparer.None`.  You want to use `StringComparer.Ordinal`.  Which can be done using DataType::AsEnumerable() with an OrderBy() clause.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MainTable");

        var column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "value";
        // Add the Column to the DataColumnCollection.
        dt.Columns.Add(column);

        var stringList = new List<string> { "All people", "Finger Print", "MyRecord_v2", "MyRecordV2", "FPrint", "AXialis" };
        foreach (string s in stringList)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["value"] = s;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Before Sort");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["value"]);
        }

        var query = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("value"), StringComparer.Ordinal);

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nSorted");
        foreach (DataRow row in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["value"]);
        }
    }
```

Results in:

```
Before Sort
  All people
  Finger Print
  MyRecord_v2
  MyRecordV2
  FPrint
  AXialis

Sorted
  AXialis
  All people
  FPrint
  Finger Print
  MyRecordV2
  MyRecord_v2
```